# Property 'zone' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, rxjs

I'm going through [meteor-ionic](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/messages-page) tutorial and get this typescript error:

```
typescript: src/pages/details/details.ts, line: 35 
            Property 'zone' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'.
```

Here is my component:

```
import { MeteorObservable } from 'meteor-rxjs';

......

MeteorObservable.call('updateRestaurantDetails',
  restaurant
).zone().subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});

......
```

And [meteor-rxjs](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs) module version is set to "^0.4.8".

What I'm doing wrong with that? and how can I fix it?

Comment: RxJS v5.5 introduced [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). And v6 - without `rxjs-compat` installed - supports only pipeable operators. See also: https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs#zone-operator

Comment: @cartant Already seen it. But haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: The snippet in your question uses a patched - i.e. not a pipeable - operator and the error message suggests that's the problem.

Comment: @cartant That's because .zone() is operator not of rxjs but of meteor-rxjs. That's clear. The main question, as always, how to fix it correctly.

Comment: Use pipeable operators and the `zoneOperator` pipeable operator. It's all in the README that's linked to in my first comment. The tutorial you are looking at is likely out-of-date, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Try importng zoneOperator and using it with pipe:

```
import { MeteorObservable } from 'meteor-rxjs';
import { zoneOperator } from 'rxjs';

......

MeteorObservable.call('updateRestaurantDetails',
  restaurant
).pipe(zoneOperator()).subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});

......
```